# How combine <16x1 cell> and <16x1 cell> into <32x1 cell> by using matlab

Tags: matlab, cell

I have two set of cells <16x1 cell> and <16x1 cell> I want combined into <32x1 cell>  by using matlab.....thanks

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 3):

Just use curly brackets and colon indexing. If you also want it Nx1 (as opposed to 1XN), then add a transpose:

```
C={C1{:},C2{:}}';
```

Or as @Luis suggests, just concatenate them with square brakets:

```
C = [C1; C2];
```

Comment: Thanks Ander but I have images from each image product 16x1 cell so i want combined each 16x1 cell with next 16x1 cell and with next 16x1 cell ........etc

Comment: @ismail aham. Is there a question there?

Comment: YES  Ander  I have images from each image product 16x1 cell so how  i can combined each 16x1 cell with next 16x1 cell and with next 16x1 cell ........etc

Comment: @ismail remember to put one of these -> ("?") whenever you have a question, it makes clearer to the rest that you actually have a question! Make a for loop and fill it as: `C=[C,nexC];`